# PHP session_start() permissions problems CentOS 8

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm getting the following error when using session_start() on CentOS 8, PHP 7.2 system.

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_ikk0j7e15bveibgk0crj508ki5, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/html/setup.php on line 26
Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/lib/php/session) in /var/www/html/setup.php on line 26
```

I've been able to fix this error in the past (on CentOS 7) by simply changing the permissions of /var/lib/php/session to 777. But this time it isn't working.

I've done the following:

- Change apache to run as the 'nidb' user
- Change ownership of /var/lib/php/session to the nidb user/group
- Change user/group of /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf to nidb/nidb
- Disable SELinux
- Restart the httpd service

What else might I be missing?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I also needed to restart the php-fpm service! That fixed it